# How to send process progress information from a long running linux command

Tags: linux, process, progress

I am planning to write a linux command which is going to process (with a custom logic) a very big file. Once this command is run, it will take hours to finish the task.

What is the best way to give eta output?

What about the idea of writing a 100 byte progress status file? In specific stages I can write bytes to the file. Say at 40% I can write 40 bytes to the file. Once the file size reaches 100 bytes size it means the process is finished. So to monitor the progress we have to check only the size of this file.

Is there any general way of handling such progress information? I don't want to include too much logic in my program for displaying the progress information. I am looking for a simple solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A log file is extremely simple and robust. Let the user find out how to project an ETA from that if they need to. Maybe create a separate tool which reads the log file in real time and produces some sort of progress indicator.

Comment: @tripleee is there any such tools available to parse the log file and to get the progress info?

Comment: I don't think there is anything ready-made for this purpose. But a program which parses `status: 12/345 done` and displays a percentage (or a progress bar, or what have you) is not hard to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *normal* way would be to set up a signal handler like `dd` does, and then you send the process a SIGUSR1 or somesuch using the `kill` command and it catches the signal and outputs a status message. Try

```
man dd
```

So, on my iMac, for example, `dd` uses `SIGINFO`, so

```
# Move a whole load of nothing to nowhere in the background
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null &
[1] 11232

# No output, till I want some a few seconds later

kill -SIGINFO 11232
12875835+0 records in
12875834+0 records out
6592427520 bytes transferred in 9.380158 secs (702805581 bytes/sec)



# No more output, till I want some a few more seconds later

kill -SIGINFO 11232
19163866+0 records in
19163865+0 records out
9811898880 bytes transferred in 14.015095 secs (700095068 bytes/sec)
```

A signal handler is pretty easy to set up, even in a shell script. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "echo Progress report..." SIGINT
echo "My process id is $$"

while : ; do
    sleep 10    # Do something - admittedly little :-)
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I got two options. 1) write a log file and then parse this log file to get the progress. 2) Write signal handler so that when a signal comes the progress information is sent as output. Is there any other method other than `kill` command to send a SIGUSER1 signal?

Comment: No, but don't worry - it won't actually kill anything. You can also make a little shell script called `status` or something that uses `pkill` to find the process name/number for the user and then sends the signal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do this nicely in Linux but if the result of your program can be an output stream like in unzip then you just can use [pv - Pipe Viewer](https://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) command. You can redirect the output into `pv` input and it will show you the progress.

In Windows you can use [Taskbar Extensions API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions?redirectedfrom=MSDN) with methods `SetProgressState` and `SetProgressValue`.